# If number is not in list return next highest number + python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, coercion

I need method of checking whether a number exists is a list/series, and if it does not returning the next highest number in the list.

For example:- in the list `nums = [1,2,3,5,7,8,20]` if I were to enter the number `4` the function would return `5` and anything `> 8 < 20` would return `20` and so on.

Below is a very basic example of the premise:

```
nums = [1,2,3,5,7,8,20]

def coerce_num(x):
    if x in nums:
        return print("yes")
    else:
        return ("next number in list")

coerce_num(9)
```

If there was a method to do this with pandas dataframe, that would be even better.

Comment: A couple of questions... 1) Is your `nums` list sorted? 2) What do you want it to happen if the user enters `21`?

Comment: Assuming the list is sorted, Python's `bisect.bisect_right` will return to you the index just after your goal.  `nums[idx-1]` might equal your value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using standard Python (`nums` doesn't need to be sorted):

```
def coerce_num(x):
    return min((n for n in nums if n >= x), default=None)
```

```
>>> coerce_num(4)
5
>>> coerce_num(9)
20
```

(added `default=None` in case no numbers are greater than `x`)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the recursive function `coerce_num(x + 1)` it will add 1 and try to search again.

**Method 1**

```
nums = [1,2,3,5,7,8,20]

def coerce_num(x):
    if x > max(nums):
        return None 
    if x in nums:
        return print("yes", x)
    else:
        coerce_num(x + 1)

coerce_num(6)
```

**Method 2**

```
nums = [1,2,3,9,7,8,20]
nums.sort()
def coerce_num(x):
    for i in nums:
        if x == i:
           return print("yes", x)
        if x < i:
           return print("next highest", i)
```

Comment: I was going to downvote this, but **IF** the list is unsorted, this is not a bad method.

Comment: This could get really inefficient if there's a big gap between numbers.

Comment: yeah, I totally understand your points. It is the simplest approach to understanding the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sorted list, use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) for an efficient binary search:

```
import bisect

nums = [1,2,3,5,7,8,20]

def coerce_num(nums, x):
    return x[bisect.bisect_left(x, nums)]

coerce_num(8, nums)
# 8

coerce_num(20, nums)
# 20

coerce_num(0, nums)
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input list is pre-sorted prior to passing into the function below.

```
import numpy as np


def check_num(list_of_nums, check):
    # use list comprehension to find values <= check
    mask=[num <= check for num in list_of_nums]
    # find max index
    maxind = np.max(np.argwhere(mask))
    # if index is last num in list then return last num (prevents error)
    # otherwise, give the next num
    if maxind==len(list_of_nums)-1:
        return list_of_nums[-1]
    else:
        return list_of_nums[maxind+1]


nums = [1,2,3,5,7,8,20]
print(check_num(nums, 6))
```